# Pipe between children

Tags: c

I want to do a program that first creates 3 processes (A) and later, creates one process more (B) and these first processes must write in a pipe that the last process read each time that process write. 
I tried something but I don't know the way to do that because the process (B) is created after the processes (A)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHILDREN 3

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;

    int fd[2];

    char buffer[100];

    char str[] = "Hello";
    char str2[] = "Hello2";
    char str3[] = "Hello3";

    for(int num_process = 0; num_process < MAX_CHILDREN; num_process++)
    {
        if(pipe(fd) == -1)
        {
            perror( "pipe Failed" );
            continue;
        }

        pid = fork();

        if(pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(pid == 0)
        { //child code

        if(num_process == 0){
                printf("Child %i (pid= %i) send string %s\n", num_process, getpid(),str);
                write(fd[1],str,strlen(str));
            }
        if(num_process == 1){
                printf("Child %i (pid= %i) send string %s\n", num_process, getpid(),str2);
                write(fd[1],str2,strlen(str2));
        }
        if(num_process == 2){
                printf("Child %i (pid= %i) send string %s\n", num_process, getpid(),str3);
                write(fd[1],str3,strlen(str3));
        }
            exit(0);
        }

        else{//parent
            printf("Im parent %i\n",getpid());
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }

    //Creating another child process from parent, this process recieves string sent from
    //childs
    pid = fork();

        if(pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    if(pid == 0){//child
    printf("The new process %i read fd pipe\n",getpid());
    if( read(fd[0],buffer,sizeof(buffer)) <= 0) //read pipe
    {
        perror("error read");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    printf("String readed : %s\n",buffer);
    }
    else{//parent
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can’t, in general, `wait` on a process that is writing to a pipe that has no readers (yet).  Deadlock will result (if much data is written).

Comment: They invented arrays so you shouldn't have to write the same code out three times.  Use `char str[][20] = { "Hello 1", "Hello 2", "Hello 3" };` or similar.

Comment: Don't wait in the parent, just create the four children (As and B)? But be aware also that writing in pipes is not atomic (it is for a certain number of characters, PIPE_BUF if I remember correctly), so strings from A processes might get mixed up.

Comment: @petre: You're right that writes are atomic up to a the size `PIPE_BUF`, but there's no risk of interference here because each of the first three children writes on a different pipe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: of course you are correct. Now I see the code overwrites the pipe descriptors in the parent in each loop, so it cannot possible read from all of them afterwards.

Comment: @petre — that too (overwritten pipe descriptors).  As noted in my answer, implicitly, by creating the 2D array `fd` instead of the 1D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a number of changes to the code.  The parent shouldn't really wait on its children until after they're all launched.  Since you create a new pipe for each of the first three children, you need to keep track of which file descriptors are in use.  You should use arrays for that, and for the strings to be sent.  Neither the `read()` nor the `write()` system calls  null-terminates strings, and you don't tell it to write a null byte at the end, so you need to tell `printf()` to print the correct information.

Those changes and sundry others lead to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_CHILDREN 3

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[MAX_CHILDREN][2];
    char buffer[100];
    const char *str[MAX_CHILDREN] = { "Hello 1", "Hello 2", "Hello 3" };

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHILDREN; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(fd[i]) == -1)
        {
            perror("pipe Failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            printf("Child %i (pid= %i) send string %s\n", i + 1, getpid(), str[i]);
            write(fd[i][1], str[i], strlen(str[i]));
            exit(i + 1);
        }
    }

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("The new process %i read fd pipe\n", getpid());
        for (int i = MAX_CHILDREN; i-- > 0; )
        {
            int nbytes;
            if ((nbytes = read(fd[i][0], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) <= 0)
            {
                perror("error read");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("String read: %.*s\n", nbytes, buffer);
        }
        exit(4);
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) >= 0)
        printf("child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, the output might be:

```
Child 1 (pid= 91027) send string Hello 1
Child 2 (pid= 91028) send string Hello 2
Child 3 (pid= 91029) send string Hello 3
The new process 91030 read fd pipe
String read: Hello 3
String read: Hello 2
String read: Hello 1
child 91027 exited with status 0x0100
child 91028 exited with status 0x0200
child 91029 exited with status 0x0300
child 91030 exited with status 0x0400
```

I reversed the order of the elements in the reading loop, mainly just for fun.  You can use a conventional `for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHILDREN; i++)` loop instead if you prefer.

Although it isn't crucial in this program, you aren't closing enough file descriptors in the children or the parent.  The parent should close the write ends of the pipes; it isn't going to be using them.  The children should close the read ends of the pipes; they aren't going to be using them.  Further, the second and third children should close the pipes opened for the first, and the third should close the pipe for the second, as they aren't going to use those, either.  If you don't do this and the fourth child looped waiting for EOF (0 bytes returned), it would hang.

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`

---

Note that an alternative design for the program would create a single pipe outside the loop and the children would all write to the same pipe.  You'd probably want to add a newline to the message strings so that the results are separate.  You'd definitely want to think about looping the read in the fourth child, and you'd need to worry about the pipe being closed properly, and so on.  It'd be a worthwhile sub-exercise to code that.